# How to print text to bottom left corner in page in C#

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, gdi, system.drawing

Code below is used to print order.
Order can have variable number of lines written out by first DrawString call.

Text

```
Bottom line1
Bottom line2
```

must appear in bottom left corner in page.

Code below uses hard coded value  `e.MarginBounds.Top + 460` to print this. 
How to remove this hard-coded value so that text is printed in bottom of page ?

```
   var doc = new PrintDocument();
   doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "PDFCreator";
   doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ProvideContent);
   doc.Print();

    void ProvideContent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("string containing variable number of lines", new Font("Arial", 12),
            Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top);

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Bottom line1\r\nBottom line2", new Font("Courier", 10), Brushes.Black,
                    e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top + 460);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measure your string, then move up that height from the bottom?

```
    void ProvideContent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("string containing variable number of lines", new Font("Arial", 12),
            Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top);


        string bottom = "Bottom line1\r\nBottom line2";
        Font courier = new Font("Courier", 10);
        Size sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(bottom, courier);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(bottom, courier, Brushes.Black,
                    e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Bottom - sz.Height);
    }
```